# Simplest image format: PPM to dataURI

Tags: javascript

I try to generate PPM image dataURI using this format [description](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) (which is theoretically very simple) in JS but my code doesn't work. My attempt is below - how can I fix it?

```js
let ppmH="P6 3 2 255 "  // PPM header: 3x2 pixel picture (total 6 pixels)  
let ppmD=[ 255,0,0,    0,255,0,    0,0,255,     // 3 pixels
           0,255,255,  255,0,255,  255,255,0];  // 3 pixels

var base64 = btoa( ppmH +String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(ppmD)));

let uri= "data:image/x-portable-pixmap;base64,"+base64;

pic.src=uri;
console.log(uri);
```

```html
<img id="pic">
```

Comment: And you say it's not working because your browser doesn't load it? Are you sure it does support this image format?

Comment: I use chrome - and not works

Comment: You mean only yours doesn't work or any ppm file doesn't work? On my FF for Android ppm files are not supported, and thus won't ever load in an img, so this wouldn't be a sign of your code not working. For instance [here are a few example files](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~incerti/IMAGES/PPM.htm) (click the jpeg links to access the ppm version) do these display in your browser? If not, your code may be working. You'd need a special viewer to know for sure.